# I have PhpMyAdmin installed on Cent os. Is there anyway i can acces it through my windows 8?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Dear readers i have stored some databases in phpmyadmin in my cent Os but i want to access it from my windows OS. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpMyAdmin doesn't 'store' databases, it is a web-based interface for querying and administering mysql databases.

To make the interface available you will need to run PHP and some form of webserver on your Centos box. Documentation for all the requirements is at https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/require.html

If you want access that interface from a Windows-based client you only need a web browser and to point it at the correct URL for the webserver.